# How to preload only part of a audio file in html5/JS?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have multiple audio files in a web page. I want them all to be ready to be played as soon as the page is loaded, but it is too heavy and useless to entirely preload all of them at once.
So I want to preload only a certain amount of the audio and load the rest iff they are played (similar to the behavior we see on YouTube par example).

How can I do this on a HTML5 page (possibly using Javascript)?

Comment: preload=meta makes sure the url lookups are primed without loading the whole file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way you're going to be able to reliably control specific preloading behavior is by loading the data yourself over websockets or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something hacky like playing the first 10% of the file in an `onload` listener.

However, from experience, I've found browsers only preload the start of audio content anyway. (If they preload *anything*: e.g. iOS, mobile chrome both refuse to preload.) In Firefox, for example, you can inspect the HTTP requests and you'll see that they're parital content requests which don't cover the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the files so that you have clipped versions.  Load those on page load, then through ajax calls load the full size files.

```
HTML: 
<div id="myAudioFilesDiv">
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
</div>


js: 
//(document.ready) code
var refresh = true;
    data = {
        'action': 'manage_reports'
        }; 
    var url = 'includes/ajax_reports.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post', 
        cache: false, 
        url: url, 
        data: data, 
        error:function(result)
        {
            $("#myAudioFilesDiv").html('failed to load full sized music files');
        },
        success:function(result)
        {
//load full sizes music files here
            $("#myAudioFilesDiv").html('<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> ');
            if(refresh) location.reload(); 
        }

    });
```

Also check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  .

Comment: Won't this simply defer loading the full audio in every case? (As opposed to OP's requirement, loading full audio *if-and-only-if* the audio is played.) Also, why use jQuery and HTML string parsing when you could simply re-assign the audio sources?

Comment: Wasn't the point to increase initial page load?  And yes, you could create a pointer and change where the pointer is pointing at, using ajax as well.

Comment: As @Jeremy says, _if-and-only-if_ . I think it is interesting to understand if it's possible to implement (client side only) a YouTube alike mechanism (it doesn't load all the video if you don't watch it). In my specific case, the audio are too big, the user is likely to play only portion of multiple files (all in the same page), but the entire audio content should be downloaded only if the user actually wants to.